# How to make copy-paste buffer in Ubuntu system-wide not lost when application closes?

Tags: ubuntu, text, copy, buffer, preserve

It is often useful to have not full of security guards system, but user-friendly system.

Typical everyday task is copypasting text between windows in Ubuntu. 
Scenario as simple as follows.
One need to fill-in the package name somewhere.
(in my case it is `compizconfig-settings-manager`, but wait).
First one need to obtain name. One may do

```
dpkg -l compiz*
```

...and get first phase of hair tearing: name not fully shown but shorted.

Then running *synaptic* and fill-in `compizco`. Package appears in list, but hitting Alt+Enter not work. 2nd stage of hair tearing is done.

Well, after get properties window one copying the package name, *closes* synaptic (of course), go to fill form window ... and see empty text buffer.
3rd final stage of hair tearing arrives.

So the question is, how to avoid 3rd phase of pain and have text buffer not lost when application closes?

I am very sorry for a bit emotional description. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> dpkg -l compiz* ...and get first phase of hair tearing: name not fully
>   shown but shorted.

Try so: dpkg -l compiz* | grep c